# How to remove data from excel file displayed in PyQt5 and refresh it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyqt5

My database application uses the Pandas library. I can display the excel file into my tableView but anytime I remove data from the mainframe and try to refresh the tableView. It gives me a keyError.

I'm trying to get it to display the refreshed table. I am attempting to drop the row that a user asks for. It works when it drops because I outputted the information but the tableView itself won't refresh and gives an error.

```py
df = pd.read_excel("filename")
model = PandasModel(df)
self.tableView.setModel(model)
self.tableView.resizeColumnsToContents()
```

```py
def DeletePlayer(self):
        global df
        choose = self.removePlayerEdit.text()
        if(choose == '0'):
            df = df.drop([0])
            print("Player deleted")
            print(df)
```

```
class PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel): 
    def __init__(self, df = pd.DataFrame(), parent=None): 
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self._df = df

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            try:
                return self._df.columns.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QtCore.QVariant()
        elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            try:
                # return self.df.index.tolist()
                return self._df.index.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QtCore.QVariant()

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        return QtCore.QVariant(str(self._df.ix[index.row(), index.column()]))

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        row = self._df.index[index.row()]
        col = self._df.columns[index.column()]
        if hasattr(value, 'toPyObject'):
            # PyQt4 gets a QVariant
            value = value.toPyObject()
        else:
            # PySide gets an unicode
            dtype = self._df[col].dtype
            if dtype != object:
                value = None if value == '' else dtype.type(value)
        self._df.set_value(row, col, value)
        return True

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        return len(self._df.index)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        return len(self._df.columns)

    def sort(self, column, order):
        colname = self._df.columns.tolist()[column]
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self._df.sort_values(colname, ascending= order == QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder, inplace=True)
        self._df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When implementing a model, you should not access the element that stores the data (dataframe) directly, because if you modify it, the model will not know what is going to generate problems, instead you should create methods that modify the internal data but use the methods as beginRemoveRows and endRemoveColumns that will notify the model of the change.

```
def removeColumn(self, col):
    if 0 <= col < self.columnCount():
        self.beginRemoveRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), col, col)
        self._df.drop(
            self._df.columns[[col]], axis=1, inplace=True
        )
        self._df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        self.endRemoveColumns()
```

I have improved my initial model to the following:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


class FloatDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    @property
    def decimals(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_decimals"):
            self._decimals = 2
        return self._decimals

    @decimals.setter
    def decimals(self, decimals):
        self._decimals = decimals

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        DBL_MAX = 1.7976931348623157e308
        editor = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(
            parent, minimum=-DBL_MAX, maximum=DBL_MAX, decimals=self.decimals
        )
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.setValue(index.data())

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.value(), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)

    def displayText(self, value, locale):
        return "{}".format(value)


class DataFrameModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    DtypeRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000
    ValueRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1001

    def __init__(self, df=pd.DataFrame(), parent=None):
        super(DataFrameModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._dataframe = df

    def setDataFrame(self, dataframe):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._dataframe = dataframe.copy()
        self.endResetModel()

    def dataFrame(self):
        return self._dataframe

    dataFrame = QtCore.pyqtProperty(
        pd.DataFrame, fget=dataFrame, fset=setDataFrame
    )

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, QtCore.Qt.Orientation, result=str)
    def headerData(
        self,
        section: int,
        orientation: QtCore.Qt.Orientation,
        role: int = QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole,
    ):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return self._dataframe.columns[section]
            else:
                return str(self._dataframe.index[section])
        return QtCore.QVariant()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return len(self._dataframe.index)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return self._dataframe.columns.size

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid() or not (
            0 <= index.row() < self.rowCount()
            and 0 <= index.column() < self.columnCount()
        ):
            return QtCore.QVariant()
        row = self._dataframe.index[index.row()]
        col = self._dataframe.columns[index.column()]
        dt = self._dataframe[col].dtype
        val = self._dataframe.iloc[row][col]
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return val
        elif role == DataFrameModel.ValueRole:
            return val
        if role == DataFrameModel.DtypeRole:
            return dt
        return QtCore.QVariant()

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        row = self._dataframe.index[index.row()]
        col = self._dataframe.columns[index.column()]
        if hasattr(value, "toPyObject"):
            # PyQt4 gets a QVariant
            value = value.toPyObject()
        else:
            # PySide gets an unicode
            dtype = self._dataframe[col].dtype
            if dtype != object:
                value = None if value == "" else dtype.type(value)
        self._dataframe.at[row, col] = value
        return True

    def flags(self, index):
        flags = (
            QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable
            | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled
            | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
            | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        )
        return flags

    def roleNames(self):
        roles = {
            QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole: b"display",
            DataFrameModel.DtypeRole: b"dtype",
            DataFrameModel.ValueRole: b"value",
        }
        return roles

    def removeRow(self, row):
        if 0 <= row < self.rowCount():
            self.beginRemoveRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row, row)
            self._dataframe.drop([row], inplace=True)
            self._dataframe.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
            self.endRemoveRows()

    def removeColumn(self, col):
        if 0 <= col < self.columnCount():
            self.beginRemoveRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), col, col)
            self._dataframe.drop(
                self._dataframe.columns[[col]], axis=1, inplace=True
            )
            self._dataframe.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
            self.endRemoveColumns()

    def sort(self, column, order):
        colname = self._dataframe.columns[column]
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self._dataframe.sort_values(
            colname, ascending=order == QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder, inplace=True
        )
        self._dataframe.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        tableview = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        tableview.setSortingEnabled(True)
        delegate = FloatDelegate(tableview)
        tableview.setItemDelegate(delegate)
        delegate.decimals = 4
        self.spinbox_row = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.button_row = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            "Delete Row", clicked=self.remove_row
        )
        self.spinbox_col = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.button_col = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            "Delete Column", clicked=self.remove_col
        )

        df = pd.DataFrame(
            np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=(100, 4)), columns=list("ABCD")
        )
        self._model = DataFrameModel(df)

        tableview.setModel(self._model)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(tableview, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        grid.addWidget(self.spinbox_row, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.button_row, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.spinbox_col, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.button_col, 1, 3)

        self.on_rowChanged()
        self.on_columnChanged()

        self._model.rowsInserted.connect(self.on_rowChanged)
        self._model.rowsRemoved.connect(self.on_rowChanged)
        self._model.columnsInserted.connect(self.on_columnChanged)
        self._model.columnsRemoved.connect(self.on_columnChanged)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_rowChanged(self):
        self.spinbox_row.setMaximum(self._model.rowCount() - 1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_columnChanged(self):
        self.spinbox_col.setMaximum(self._model.columnCount() - 1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def remove_row(self):
        row = self.spinbox_row.value()
        self._model.removeRow(row)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def remove_col(self):
        col = self.spinbox_col.value()
        self._model.removeColumn(col)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I was hoping you would respond because I used your model. Thank you it works.